# Is there a flutter equivalent for intro JS?

Tags: flutter, dart-pub, intro.js

I'm creating a flutter app that will have assorted functionality per page, it would be good to explain different aspects of the page to the user but bad to always show those instructions, as past first use they become redundant. In the past on web applications I've used [Intro JS](https://introjs.com/) which can be hugely helpful to guide the user through different functions on a page.

Is there an equivalent to this in flutter? Ideally a package or widget that would allow you to display info boxes/tooltip type widgets that contain text and point to specific parts of the screen. This widget/sets of widgets could be called programatically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is what you want: https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what intro.js is but from pub.dev, look at package
  showcaseview